# Sort by timestamp for get_metrics_statistic boto3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sorting, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have been trying to get metrics from AWS through boto3 `get_metric_statistic`,
but based on their documentation, it is said that data point will not be output in chronological order.

Therefore, the only way here is to sort by myself, but I am facing some trouble and would like to seek for help. I tried to clean my data as much as I could into a list as shown below.

```
LatencyList = [[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 12, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 1774.8832250541395,
[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 1636.6231504945638], 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 9, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 1872.890265292699], 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 1993.080265911609], 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 7, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 1613.9198443579767], 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 11, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 1785.7875248218666], 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 1685.3907645207926]]]
```

Is there any way I can sort this list into chronological order? Thank you very much.

I tried using `sort()` or `sorted()`, by they didn't work.

Below is a sample of my code:

```
LatencyList = []
response = get_metrics_statistic() 
##I didn't paste my full code for metrics here, but I managed to output from this function

for item in response["Datapoints"]:
    Average = item["Average"]
    Time = item['Timestamp']
    Latency = [Time,Average]
    LatencyList.append(Latency)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom key which tells sort what to sort upon. This would be something like: `LatencyList.sort(key=itemgetter(0))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
LatencyList = []     
for item in response['Datapoints']:
         if item['Timestamp']:
            item['Timestamp'] = str(item['Timestamp'])
            LatencyList.append(item)
LatencyList = sorted(LatencyList, key = lambda i: i['Timestamp'])
```

I have converted time to string but it is optional, have use because of json render

**Second option**

```
from operator import itemgetter

LatencyList = []     
for item in response['Datapoints']:
    LatencyList.append(item)
LatencyList = sorted(LatencyList, key=itemgetter('Timestamp'))
```

it is faster than lambda